# Eloquent "grandfather" relashionship condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

School have books and students.
Book have pages.

How can i get all pages from all books where `school_id = 1` ? I tried the code below, but i didn't worked.

```php
Page::whereHas('book.school', function($query) {
    $query->where('id', '=', 1);
})->get()->toJson();
```

Also, what if i'd like to get all pages from `book_id = 1` and `school_id = 1` ?
I need to use school_id here just to check if the book we are getting the pages is from the same school as the logged student.

Comment: Are you sure about `book.school`? Last time I checked it was necessary to nest `whereHas` for each relationship level.

Comment: Actually i wasn't sure about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way, assuming `Book belongsTo School`:

```
Page::whereHas('book', function($query) {
    $query->where('school_id', '=', 1);
})->get();
```

complete solution:

```
Page::whereHas('book', function($q) {
    $q->whereHas('school', function ($q) {
       $q->where('id', '=', 1);
    });
})->get();
```

Comment: I hope we will have your pull request `Improve has for nested relations` merged and available in Laravel 5. I'm like anxious forever for that one.

Comment: Yeah, that one adds some consistency to the Eloquent. I'll find some time soon to improve the PR so it comes with L5.

Comment: Didn't know i could nest queries, thanks. Btw, your PR is really great addition to Eloquent, hope to see it merged soon.